# Como indicar quantos números iguais existem entre dois vetores?

Tags: java

Estou com esse exercício aqui da faculdade:

> Escreva um programa em java que recebe dois vetores de tamanhos
>   diferentes e em seguida indica quantos números iguais existem entre
>   esses dois vetores.

Não estou sabendo desenvolver a lógica, por enquanto o código está apenas com a leitura dos arrays:

```
    package vetores2;
   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ex02 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] vetor  = new int[10];
    int[] vetor2= new int[9];
    int totalIgual = 0;

    System.out.println(" Insira os valores do primeiro vetor");
    for(int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
        vetor[i] = entrada.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(" Insira os valores do segundo vetor");
    for(int i = 0; i < vetor2.length; i++) {
        vetor2[i] = entrada.nextInt();
    }
```

A partir dai que não estou sabendo dar continuidade...

Comment: Só vetor ou você pode usar `Collection` dentro do método?

Comment: Tecnicamente, como sou iniciante não deveria usar o, mas usando ou não é válido. bom que aprendo com mais praticidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução simples poderia ser comparar cada valor do vetor com cada valor do vetor2, caso encontre, usa um contador que vai incrementando caso encontre um igual.

```
int contador = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < vetor2.length; j++) {
          if(vetor[i] == vetor2[j])
              contador++;
     }
}
```

Comment: Eu havia feito dessa forma, mas percebi que, por exemplo, se ambos os vetores possuírem o valor 2, mas no vetor1 o índice for [2] e no vetor2 o índice for [4], não sera somado no total

Comment: @Yan Luis independentemente do indice, cada valor do vetor1 é comparado com todos os valores do vetor2 .

Comment: Puxa, então interpretei o código de forma errada. muito obrigado, Jorge!

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar, pode-se resolver utilizando `Collection` com o seguinte método:

```
public Integer[] encontrarInterseccao(Integer[] vetor1, Integer[] vetor2) {
  Set<Integer> conjunto1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(vetor1));
  Set<Integer> conjunto2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(vetor2));

  conjunto1.retainAll(conjunto2);

  return conjunto1.toArray(new Integer[conjunto1.size()]);
}
```

E fazendo uso da seguinte forma (aplicada ao código de exemplo):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(encontrarInterseccao(vetor, vetor2)));
```

Para utilizar desta forma declare os vetores como abaixo:

```
Integer[] vetor = new Integer[10];
Integer[] vetor2 = new Integer[9];
```

---

> [**`Set`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)
>
> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

Em tradução livre:

> Uma coleção que não contém itens duplicados. Mais formalmente, sets não contém pares de elementos e1 e e2 em caso de e1.equals(e2). Como sugere o nome, essa interface é uma abstração do modelo matemático "conjunto".

---

Você também pode utilizar uma solução com `Java 8` baseada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37788939/3388148) do `Stack Overflow`:

```
public int[] encontrarInterseccao(int[] vetor1, int[] vetor2) {
  return Arrays.stream(vetor1)
          .filter(x -> Arrays.stream(vetor2).anyMatch(y -> y == x))
          .toArray();
}
```

Mas tenha em mente que nesta solução, se houverem elementos repetidos, irão aparecer também várias vezes no resultado.

Comment: Devo dizer que, apesar de ser fã de `streams`, eu não curti a sua alternativa usando `streams`. No trabalho usamos muito uma estratégia chamada (internamente como uma piada) de "matar dragões", ou "matar calangos" quando o problema consiste de coleções pequenas. Basicamente, consiste em transformar uma das coleções em uma estrutura de "memória assossiativa" de modo que, em normalmente `O(1)`, eu consiga saber a prioridade devida. Normalmente usamos para hidratar entidades tendo apenas os códigos delas e uma lista de identidades, mas nesse caso seria verificar se pertence ao conjunto ou não